# SQL Query need to show blank records

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where i'm selecting 50 ids from the DB and grouping them by the id.

The only problem is that only 34 exists in the DB so it only shows 34 results.

My desired result is to show 50 results with the ones that don't exists in.

Is this possible?

Thanks

**My query**

```
SELECT no, count(no) as visits FROM DB 
WHERE (no = '1' or no = '2'  or no = '3' or no = '4' or no = '5')
GROUP BY no
```

This example will only give me 3 records even though i'm selecting 5 records

Comment: Looks like a 'left join' will be helpful. It would be better if you can provide some real code as an example.

Comment: @RollingBoy I've added my query now

Comment: @jms yes i'd like to show the blank records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with noTable
as 
( select 1 as no
union
  select 2
union 
  select 3
union 
  select 4
union 
  select 5
)

select noTable.no,count(*) 
  from noTable inner join DB 
  on noTable.no = DB.no group by noTable.no
union
select noTable.no,0
  from noTable left join DB
  on noTable.no = DB.no
  where DB.no is null;
```

Might not be elegant if there're 50 id...

Answer (score 1):

You could add a tally table using [WITH](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCEQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx&ei=OyycTbvUA4WhOrjDkIIH&usg=AFQjCNE_EOC2EHMFw9nifV_MhE1VrIQUSg&sig2=kTILDj8iNij5KnRHq5erGw) and [LEFT JOIN](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCsQFjAC&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178429%28v=sql.80%29.aspx&ei=5yycTb2nDo-bOtGuwJYH&usg=AFQjCNECHCUurem6ToxSlksMxCJCRhBEeg&sig2=25fJ1hJAPPtUyLNKocpAwg) your original table with the tally table.

```
;with q (no) AS (
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT no + 1
  FROM   q
  WHERE  no < 50
)
SELECT  q.no
        , CASE WHEN db.no IS NOT NULL 
               THEN COUNT(q.no)
               ELSE 0 
          END AS Visits
FROM    q
        LEFT JOIN db ON db.no = q.no
GROUP BY
        no
```